# Using Linq Aggregate to add elements of a List

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

As I understand the `Aggregate` extension method, I should be able to use it to iterate through a collection and perform operations on the current and previous element; for example:

```
var totalSum = myIntCollection.Aggregate( (a,b) => a + b);
```

However, can (and if so how) can I use this to add class properties; for example:

```
totalSum = MyCollection.Aggregate((a, b) => a.MyInt + b.MyInt);
```

Given that MyCollection is a `List<MyClass>` and `MyClass` looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to compile the above statement, it tells me that it can't implicitly covert int to MyClass.

So, my question is: why is it giving this error, and is there a way around it?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the purpose of Aggregate, to be honest. It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve, but if you *are* just trying to sum properties, the `Sum` method is definitely the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood on what `Aggregate` method operates. It does not "perform operations on the current and previous element".

It performs operations on an **accumulator** and **current element**.

So, in your first example `var totalSum = myIntCollection.Aggregate( (a,b) => a + b);`, `a` is not a previous element; it represents the sum of all elements that appear before current element (`b`). I think your misunderstanding is due to the fact that the `Aggregate` method in your case started by adding the first two elements.

Anyway, as **@Sayse** and **@Jon Skeet** pointed out, you're better of with using `Sum` in this case:

```
var totalSum = MyCollection.Sum(item => item.MyInt);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way around it would be

```
MyCollection.Sum(a => a.MyInt)
```